# Pandas: Subset Data Where Multiple Row Values Are Not All The Same

Tags: python, pandas

Using this example data, I want to create a subset for all the rows in which the string values in columns A, B and C are not all the same.

```
    A    B       C      names
0   cat  cat     cat    mark
1   dog  dog     dog    kate
2   dog  dog     rat    james
3   rat  cat     dog    joe
```

The subset would look like this:

```
2   dog  dog     rat    james
3   rat  cat     dog    joe
```

Rows 2 and 3 are returned because both have one or more values in columns A, B and C which are not the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the above dataframe is `df`, you can select those rows by checking if the value in B and C are both equal to A:

```
In [56]: mask = df[['A', 'B', 'C']].eq(df['A'], axis=0).all(axis=1)

In [57]: mask
Out[57]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool

In [59]: df[~mask]
Out[59]:
     A    B    C  names
2  dog  dog  rat  james
3  rat  cat  dog    joe
```

The reason we have to use `eq` instead of just `df[['B', 'C']] == df['A']` is because this last statement will try to match the index of `df['A']` to the columns of the dataframe `df[['B','C']]`.

Comment: Very elegant, would never have thought of `eq`. I can't seem to accept your answer from my mobile but will do asap from my laptop